# How to maintain stable and development version of a website?

Tags: .htaccess, version-control

I am trying to build a website from scratch, and I am pretty new to this. I was wondering how I can keep a stable version published while I am further developing.

I was thinking of having two folders on my server `/Dev` and `/Stable` and then setting the Directory Index in the `.htaccess` file to point to the Stable version.

Is this an effective way of doing this?

Comment: You could use two separate subdomains, that's often much less hassle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice for this task it to use different domains for this, as Pekka points out. You could have www.website.com for the usually so called "live" version and e.g. test.website.com or dev.website.com or staging.website.com - with password protection - for development.

But that might be a monetary issue, so one thing you can (and maybe should) always do is to run the complete website as a local version on your computer - e.g. using XAMPP in case you're not fluent with sql / web / ftp / mail server setup.

In any case it's a great personal skill improvement if you learn how to setup and run more or less the same environment your website is running under on your local machine!

Furthermore you might want to start using a versioning software like e.g. **Subversion** or even more sophisticated **git**. That way you can further enhance/develop your code and nevertheless do hotfixes on your running version without having to maintain 2 different file trees.

Answer (score 1):

If they're static sites, then this should suffice, although it'd be better to have a virtual host set up for each, so you can test them on yoursite.com and dev.yoursite.com, for example.

If it's going to be a full-fledged webapp, then you have to be careful with having them both on the same server because of any possible shared resources (mostly files and databases).

Consider an approach like Capistrano takes (which is a great tool that you could use for deployment, btw)

- /var/www/yoursite/releases/2012-03-03_0907
- /var/www/yoursite/releases/2012-03-02_1234
- /var/www/yoursite/releases/dev -> 2012-03-03_0907
- /var/www/yoursite/releases/stable -> 2012-03-02_1234

where `dev` and `stable` are symlinks, so you may have to configure apache to allow this.

Then deployment consists of creating a new release and updating a symlink. You can configure apache to use the symlinks directly, so that you decouple apache configs from updating the site.